# How to Estimate Times for Projects in a Programming Workshop?

Tags: teaching, code, workshop

I am going to be teaching a workshop on Julia for data science and scientific computing soon. I came up with a plan that has a lot more than we will be able to do (just in case), but was wondering about how to come up with a good estimate for how far along we will get. I find this hard to estimate since for most of the assignments I could do them really quickly, but that's because I am experience in the language and the biggest hurdle will be learning the documentation, syntax, and all the special issues of a new language.

That said, do you have any good heuristics for how long projects will take in a workshop? It's hard to know the exact number of students right now, but I think it will be anywhere from 10~30, and I'd assume more students would make it go slower. I thought of doing something like "this takes me 5 minutes, so plan 20 minutes", but the number 20 has no basis in reality because I have never done this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Test drive

Grab a couple of local students of comparable level and have them do the assignments.

Your own speed is not indicative - something that takes you five minutes may take ten minutes or may be incomplete after an hour; only practical experience can show how it will turn out.

In addition, usually setting up a working development environment can be a major time sink - if people use their own hardware and various operating systems, then some of them can waste a lot of time until they are able to run a 'hello world' program; you should have a clear plan on how you will handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very good at judging how long things take. To work around this, I prepare a number of different versions of each exercise. From hardest to easiest, I provide

- A statement of objectives (i.e., write a function that does X, Y, and Z)
- A detailed description of the objectives, input and output arguments, and some helpful functions
- Some framework code with comments describing what needs to be done and where
- Nearly complete code which only needs a few lines of additional code
- Complete code with instructions on how to run it and an explanation of what it does

Depending on the specifics, I often start with a simple exercise to gauge the level of experience that the students have. If the experience is fairly uniform, I then try and provide the appropriate level exercise. I make the first real exercise too hard, I provide a hint to speed things up. If it is too easy, I choose a more difficult level for the next activity. If there is a lot of diversity in the students, I let them know that they can choose the difficulty.

I do this both for ungraded workshops and graded programming/practical classes. In my graded classes the students just get a statement of objectives for the final project. During the course of the class I let them build up to that however they want.